# Order of operations: Matrix product and hadamard product

Tags: matrices, convention, hadamard-product

Is there any convention of the order of operations in a term with both ordinary matrix multiplication and hadamard (elementwise) multiplication?

Obviously, 
$$ A ( b \circ c ) \ne (A b) \circ c  $$

But how is $ A b \circ c  $ (without parentheses) conventionally interpreted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably no convention, and if there is it is not sufficiently well known to be unambiguous. Authors using such a mixture would either have to declare their convention or (better still) use brackets for both cases.